# Hidden Parameters for drop down selections using tlist/SQL

Tags: sql, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor, tlist, powerschool

To give you some perspective on the question on hand, I created a report for a student information system which pulls student logs, based on the selectable criteria from a set of drop downs, on an html page. The drop down lists are populated using tlist/sql. The current report only has 3 drop downs:

Start Date, End Date, and Sports Logs. Here is the code for the Sports drop down:

```
SELECT DISTINCT log.logtypeid,
CASE WHEN log.subtype is null THEN ' ' ELSE log.subtype END subID, 
lt.Name logtype, 
CASE WHEN to_char(st.ValueT) is null THEN ' - NONE' ELSE ' - ' || to_char(st.ValueT) END subtype
FROM log
INNER JOIN gen lt ON log.logtypeid = lt.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN gen st ON st.Name = to_char(lt.ID)
AND st.value = log.subtype
AND st.Cat = 'subtype'
WHERE lt.Cat = 'logtype'
AND log.logtypeid = '3935'
ORDER BY subtype
```

Now in order for the report to pull as it was designed, I believe I need each selection from the Sports drop down to pull some data that will not be listed or displayed in the drop down. In its current state, and the way it should stay is...

```
Sports - Baseball
Sports - Bowling
Sports - Boys Basketball
Sports - Boys Golf
Sports - Dance
Sports - Diving
```

Sports represents logtypeid 3935. Baseball is subtype 101, bowling is subtype 102, etc.

For the report to pull the data as designed, there are two additional subtypes that need to be pulled, but unfortunately they hold a different logtypeid, 626. So if student id 1 has a 3935(logtypeid), 101(subtype), it should also pull his 626(logtypeid) 29(subtype) and 626(logtypeid) 43(subtype), if he/she has them.

```
Data Example:

STUDENTID       LOGTYPEID       SUBTYPE
  6382             626             27
  6382             626             41
  6382             626             38
  6382             626             43
  6382             626             29
  6382            3935            109
  6382            3935            117
  6383             626             43
  6383             626             30
  6383             626             43
  6383             626             25
  6383             626             43
  6383             626             14
  6383            3935            117
  6400             626             38
  6401             626             28
  6401             626             36
  6401            3935            110
  6402              15              3
  6405            3935            101
  6405            3935            115
  6405             626             29
  6405             626             43
```

so to simplify(I hope), all 3935's should be displayed in the Sports dropdown, with there corresponding subtypes. Any studentid that holds that criteria selected(can only select one sport at a time), the report should also pull there logtypeid 626, subtype 29, AND logtypeid 626 subtype 43. I have tried everything I could possibly think of. I believe the answer may fall between CASE WHEN but I am unsure of the syntax. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: anyone able to offer any insight? =(

Comment: last attempt to get some possible insight, thanks ahead